# Out of the box function to place the long tail of levels in a feature as 'other'?

Tags: r

Suppose I'm in the middle of a dplyr chain and want to bin the long tail of less frequent levels into other:

```
diamonds$clarity %>% table %>% data.frame %>% arrange(desc(Freq))
     .  Freq
1  SI1 13065
2  VS2 12258
3  SI2  9194
4  VS1  8171
5 VVS2  5066
6 VVS1  3655
7   IF  1790
8   I1   741
```

In this case I might want to keep SI1, VS2 and SI2 and just rename the rest as 'clarity_other'.

How might I do that? Is there an out of the box function? I'm presuming this is a common transformation, e.g. in this case I'm creating dummy variables and want to bin the long tail of levels in some features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forcats::fct_lump_n()` to keep only the n most frequent groups and collapse the rest:

```
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

diamonds %>% 
  mutate(lumped = fct_lump_n(clarity, 3, other_level = "clarity_other")) %>%
  count(lumped)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  lumped            n
  <ord>         <int>
1 SI2            9194
2 SI1           13065
3 VS2           12258
4 clarity_other 19423
```

Comment: You could also do `count(lumped = fct_lump_n(clarity, 3, other_level = "clarity_other"))`